# Can you transform an html unordered list, scraped with beautifulsoup, into json data on python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to produce json data from a list of items in an html. I scraped the text with beautifulsoup but I want to extract only text and put it into a json format, like this:

[This is the idea, what I have and what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yOpM.png)

I tried create a dictionary where the extracted data was a function of its own, but what I instead got was that the description used in my find() is actually the same for all of them, so I just keep getting the first value for all of them.

```
for nutrients in soup_level1.findAll("ul", attrs={"class": "product-annex-list"}):
nutrition_data = {
    "energi1": nutrients.find("span", attrs={"class": "annex-value pull-right"}).text.encode("utf-8"),
    "energi2": nutrients.find("span", attrs={"class": "annex-value pull-right"}).text.encode("utf-8"),
    "fett": nutrients.find("span", attrs={"class": "annex-value pull-right"}).text.encode("utf-8"),
    
}
```

Maybe there's a way to use some sort of index in the find? or maybe there's a more efficient way to use findAll()?

Or is there some module that converts straight into json maybe?

Comment: Can you share the URL you're scraping?

Comment: @baduker I think I can: http://coop.se/handla
But I also used selenium to pick out an item and open up the nutritional data which is behind a javascript thing

Answer (score 0):

If you've already used `selenium` what you could do to get the data is scrape for product urls and then use the `coop.se` API to get pure `JSON` for each product with all the info you will (ever) need.

Each product url ends with a product id. Grab that, drop it into the API url and get the JSON.

In the example below, I'm scraping all product urls but I'm using a hand-picked sample to illustrate the point. However, if you want go through all of them you'd have to filter `all_product_urls` for those items that don't have nutrition information (like toilet paper).

The code:

```
import json
import time

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.coop.se/handla/")
time.sleep(4)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="inner-wrapper"]/a')

all_product_urls = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]

sample_item_urls = [
    "https://www.coop.se/handla/varor/mejeri-agg/juice-mjolkdryck/drickfardig-juice/juice-apelsin-7310867561006",
    "https://www.coop.se/handla/varor/ost/matost/fetaost-salladsost/feta-23-7350002402658",
    "https://www.coop.se/handla/varor/mejeri-agg/bak-matlagning/agg-jast/agg-12-pack-7300156482679",
    "https://www.coop.se/handla/varor/mejeri-agg/matfett/margarin/smor-normalsaltat-7310865005168",
]


def get_item_id(item_url):
    return item_url.split("/")[-1].split("-")[-1]


def get_item_data(item_url):
    api_url = f"https://www.coop.se/ws/v2/coop/users/anonymous/products/" \
              f"{get_item_id(item_url)}?fields=FULL&storeId=016001"
    return requests.get(api_url).json()


def dump_data(product_data, item_url):
    with open(f"{item_url.split('/')[-1]}.json", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(product_data, json_file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)


for item_url in sample_item_urls:
    data = get_item_data(item_url)
    # dump_data(data, item_url)
    try:
        print(f"\nProduct: {data['breadcrumbs']['breadcrumbs'][0]['name']}")
        for food_info in data["foodAnnex"]:
            print(food_info)
            # print(f"{food_info['name']} - {food_info['value']}")
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

This prints:

```
Product: Juice Apelsin
{'name': 'Energi', 'value': '45 Kilokalori'}
{'name': 'Energi', 'value': '180 Kilojoule'}
{'name': 'Fett', 'value': '0 Gram'}
{'name': 'Varav mättat fett', 'value': '0 Gram'}
{'name': 'Kolhydrat', 'value': '9.0 Gram'}
{'name': 'Varav sockerarter', 'value': '9.0 Gram'}
{'name': 'Fiber', 'value': '0.4 Gram'}
{'name': 'Protein', 'value': '0.7 Gram'}
{'name': 'Salt', 'value': '0 Gram'}
{'name': 'Vitamin C', 'value': '28 Milligram'}
```

If you uncomment the last line you'll get a "pretty-print" product info:

```
Product: Feta 23 %
Energi - 1140 Kilojoule
Energi - 275 Kilokalori
Fett - 23 Gram
Varav mättat fett - 16 Gram
Kolhydrat - 1 Gram
Varav sockerarter - 0.5 Gram
Protein - 16 Gram
Salt - 2.5 Gram
```

Finally, if you feel like it, you can dump product's JSON data to a file. Just uncomment the `# dump_data(data, item_url)` line. This will produce JSON files:

```
agg-12-pack-7300156482679.json
feta-23-7350002402658.json
juice-apelsin-7310867561006.json
smor-normalsaltat-7310865005168.json
```